# Developing for CUDA on "cheap" GPUs

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I develop algorithms in CUDA on my desktop which should later run on a server.

Is it okay to use a recent low end card (like compute capability 2.1) to get all the nice debug and profiling features and then put the code on the server with the high end card (with the same cc)? Would I just need to adjust the thread/mesh sizes, or does it change everything™.

Example: I would develop on a [Quadro 600](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadro-600-us.html) and the server would use a [Tesla C2075](http://www.nvidia.com/object/personal-supercomputing.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long your kernel call and kernel itself is scalable you have no problem.

Check out this question:

[CUDA development on different cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473046/cuda-development-on-different-cards)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues, like memory bandwith being different (25.6 GiB/s on Quadro and 148 GiB/s on Tesla, according to your links), or different number of SMs (the driver could distribute blocks across SMs differently). However, in most cases such small diffrences are of minor importance.

Answer (score 1):

If the server has more than one GPU installed then you need to change your code to run on Multi-GPU to fully leverage the power of the server. Although the same code will run fine but on a single card.

In case there's only one card on server; general rule of thumb is that you **do not need** to change any line of code to harness the power of the stronger GPU as the driver distributes the load among SMs automatically.